# Animation on iphone 4 is different from simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I tried this code on XCode 4 then it works, but it doesn't even appear on iphone 4 real handset.

```
    UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2-2.PNG"];
    UIImageView *myimageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myimage];
    myimageView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 20, 20);

    CABasicAnimation *animation = nil; 
    CATransform3D transform;

    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1.57f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
    NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]; 
    [animation setToValue:value];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES]; 
    [animation setDuration:0.5f];
    [animation setRepeatCount:2.0];
    [[myimageView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"180"];

    [self.view addSubview:myimageView];
```

any help what I should do to make it works on real handset ?

Comment: Try `UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2-2.png"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the image wasn't in the current version of the project, but it was on a previous version of it, so that somehow the simulator linked the image from the previous version of my project but on real device it wasn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Probably like Roman mentioned. Make sure your file name is correct.

The filename is case sensitive on real devices but not on the simulator.